# Add navigation route to Flutter card

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I have a card scroll menu where each card has a "Read more".

How can I Route from the current "Read more" to an individual page?

The lower picture shows a slightly modified version.

I had to remove a bit of code due to stackoverflow but this was just layout code.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MyApp(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

var cardAspectRatio = 12.0 / 16.0;
var widgetAspectRatio = cardAspectRatio * 1.2;

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var currentPage = images.length - 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: images.length - 1);
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = controller.page;
      });
    });

    return Container(

      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 12.0, right: 12.0, top: 30.0, bottom: 8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[              
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                child: Row(           
                  children: <Widget>[            
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xFF00E9FF),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 22.0, vertical: 6.0),
                          child: Text("xxxxxx",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                    ),
                    Text("xxxxxxx",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF00E9FF)))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CardScrollWidget(currentPage),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      itemCount: images.length,
                      controller: controller,
                      reverse: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 120.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(

                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[

                  )


class CardScrollWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  var currentPage;
  var padding = 20.0;
  var verticalInset =20.0;

  CardScrollWidget(this.currentPage);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: widgetAspectRatio,
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, contraints) {
        var width = contraints.maxWidth;
        var height = contraints.maxHeight;

        var safeWidth = width - 2 * padding;
        var safeHeight = height - 2 * padding;

        var heightOfPrimaryCard = safeHeight;
        var widthOfPrimaryCard = heightOfPrimaryCard * cardAspectRatio;

        var primaryCardLeft = safeWidth - widthOfPrimaryCard;
        var horizontalInset = primaryCardLeft / 2;

        List<Widget> cardList = new List();

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          var delta = i - currentPage;
          bool isOnRight = delta > 0;

          var start = padding +
              max(
                  primaryCardLeft -
                      horizontalInset * -delta * (isOnRight ? 15 : 1),
                  0.0);

          var cardItem = Positioned.directional(
            top: padding + verticalInset * max(-delta, 0.0),
            bottom: padding + verticalInset * max(-delta, 0.0),
            start: start,
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      offset: Offset(3.0, 6.0),
                      blurRadius: 10.0)
                ]),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: cardAspectRatio,
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(images[i], fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                              child: Text(title[i],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 25.0,
                                      fontFamily: "SF-Pro-Text-Regular")),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 12.0, bottom: 12.0),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 22.0, vertical: 6.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color(0xFF00E9FF),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                child: Text("Read more",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
          cardList.add(cardItem);
        }
        return Stack(
          children: cardList,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation?

Comment: Ideally you would Wrap readmore in gesture detector and then use ```Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>IndividualPage()));```. You can either fetch data for the pressed card in individual page or send data from the card itself as an arguement.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap "read more" text with `InkWell` and navigate to other screen `onTap`..

```
InkWell(
  child: Text("Read More"),
  onTap:(){
    // Navigate here
  },
)
```

Comment: But each card should have a different page route when clicking on read more. Wouldn't your solution lead me always to the same page?

Comment: Well, no.. because..like you said..if there are many `Card`s..I'm sure that you'll definitely have some index to track them..right..!so..you can use that to dynamically navigate user each time to a different screen..